# Assigning incremental filenames within a cycle

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I have a function that takes an image and gives it a file name. The function is part of a cycle that acquires multiple image files:

```
def cameracycle(self):
    print "cam cycle start"
    self.capture(30)
    print "cam cycle sleep"
    sleep(270)
    print "cam cycle second capture"
    self.capture(30)

def capture (self,length):
    self.camera.start_recording('1.h264')   
    self.camera.wait_recording(length)          
    self.camera.stop_recording()
```

Every time 'capture' is called the program writes over the file "1.h264". How can I write it so that the filename increases incrementally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable `video_count` to keep track of what number is next.

```
video_count = 0
def capture (self,length):
    video_count+=1
    self.camera.start_recording(str(video_count) + '.h264')   
    self.camera.wait_recording(length)          
    self.camera.stop_recording()
```

---

You may find it neater to make this an attribute of the function, like so:

```
def capture (self,length):
    capture.video_count+=1
    self.camera.start_recording(str(video_count) + '.h264')   
    self.camera.wait_recording(length)          
    self.camera.stop_recording() 
capture.video_count = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable :

```
currentid = 0

def capture(self, length):
    global currentid
    currentid += 1
    self.camera.start_recording(str(currentid) + '.h264')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a capture counter to your class this way :

```py
class MyClassName(object):

    counter = 0

    def cameracycle(self):
        print "cam cycle start"
        self.capture(30)
        print "cam cycle sleep"
        sleep(270)
        print "cam cycle second capture"
        self.capture(30)

    def capture (self,length):
        MyClassName.counter += 1
        self.camera.start_recording('{}.h264'.format(MyClassName.counter)) 
        self.camera.wait_recording(length)          
        self.camera.stop_recording()
```